# Gluster strange issue with shared mount point like seprate mount.

Tags: cluster-computing, mount, glusterfs

I have two nodes and for experiment i have install glusterfs and create volume and successfully mounted on own node, but if i create file in node1 it is not showing in node2, look like both behaving like they are separate.

node1

```
10.101.140.10:/nova-gluster-vol
                      2.0G  820M  1.2G  41% /mnt
```

node2

```
10.101.140.10:/nova-gluster-vol
                      2.0G   33M  2.0G   2% /mnt
```

volume info split brian

```
$ sudo gluster volume heal nova-gluster-vol info split-brain
Gathering Heal info on volume nova-gluster-vol has been successful

Brick 10.101.140.10:/brick1/sdb
Number of entries: 0

Brick 10.101.140.20:/brick1/sdb
Number of entries: 0
```

test

node1

```
$ echo "TEST" > /mnt/node1
$ ls -l /mnt/node1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Oct 27 17:47 /mnt/node1
```

node2 (file isn't there, while they are shared mount)

```
$ ls -l /mnt/node1
ls: cannot access /mnt/node1: No such file or directory
```

What i am missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Iptable solved my problem

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 49152 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: How did you find it? esp. the port number?